# Joining three or more tables using django ORM

Tags: django, join, orm

I have designed my models such way that all the models will have one to one relation on auth_user table which is `User`. For your quick reference I am pasting the Picture below

[image]

Now I want to select all the data related to username which are in tables BasicDetails, Department and Project. The below query is not fetching the results.

`User.objects.select_related().get(username='user1')`

Can someone help me on this?

-Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use prefetch_related for efficiency, since your relation is reverse (you want to access the other records from User and not the other way around):

```
u = User.objects.prefetch_related('project_set', 'department_set', 'basicdetails_set').get(username='user1')
```

This will not generate a single query, but Django will use caching techniques to effectively produce less possible db overhead. If I recall correctly it will produce 4 queries (a single join in 4 tables might be slower anyway, depending on number of records, indexes etc). The benefit is that on subsequent requests no queres will be generated. For example to get a user's projects:

```
u.project_set.all() #hits the db
u.project_set.all() #cached version, no db hit
```

For more info see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships.

EDIT: what is `project_set`?

If your Project model is defined like this

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

then you can do `Project.objects.get(pk=1).user` to access the user associated to a project instance, but how would you do the opposite (get all projects of a certain user)? Django will automatically include a '_set' property to the other model for convenience. Therefore we can get the projects of a certain user like this:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user_objects = u.project_set.all()
```

However if you want to explicitly set a name for this reverse relation, django allows you define the ForeignKey with a `related_name` keyword argument like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='projects')
```

Now instead of `.project_set` you could use `.projects` to access a user's projects:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user_objects = u.projects.all()
```

Comment: I am just wondering what would be the project_set? the fields in project table?

Comment: Hello, I just updated my answer. I hope not to confuse you, my English is not so good :)

Comment: Hey petrid, DO you know how to merge multiple `user_object`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. I just checked the code in case I missed something and it's all working. Did you find something wrong? Are u refering to my edits? I've edited the answer a couple of times in an effort to improve its English.